# How to rotate an ArcSegment around ellipse center

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 shapes: one ellipse and one circle.I want to rotate circle around ellipse's center.

```
<Path Stroke="Indigo" StrokeThickness="3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
      Data="M 50 50 A 50 50 0 0 0 42.5 26.2">
      <Path.RenderTransform>
           <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
      </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
<Ellipse Stroke="Black" Width="50" Height="50"/>
```

Here is what I want

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that both shapes use the same coordinate system. You could draw both as a `Path`, one with an `EllipseGeometry`, the other with a `PathGeometry`, in a common Canvas parent. The upper left corner of the Canvas defines the coordinate origin.

```
<Canvas Margin="100">
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="50" RadiusY="50"/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Path Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,-50">
                    <ArcSegment Point="42.5,-26.2" Size="50,50"
                                IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
                </PathFigure>
                <PathGeometry.Transform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="15"/>
                </PathGeometry.Transform>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Now adjust the ArcSegment's `Point` and the RotateTransform's `Angle` according to your needs.

---

Update: you could add an animation that constantly rotates the arc segment like this:

```
<Path Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,-50">
                <ArcSegment Point="42.5,-26.2" Size="50,50"
                            IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="transform"/>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="transform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                        To="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```

Or without explictly naming the RotateTransform:

```
<Path Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="0,-50">
                <ArcSegment Point="42.5,-26.2" Size="50,50"
                            IsLargeArc="False" SweepDirection="Clockwise"/>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform/>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.Transform.Angle"
                        To="360" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question if you actually wanted to animate the arc segment, or probably just set it to some value from code behind. Do you just want an animation that runs forever?

Comment: yes,I know how to do it from code behind.thanks! I trying to add a Storyboard from xaml.<Storyboard Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                         From="0" To="360"
        />.Having a problem.

Comment: Oh,I could use Data.Transform.Angle.Awsome! I got it